# String literal reference class

Tags: c++, c++14

In `C++1y`, can I have a reference class that binds to a string literal but not to `char*` or `char[]&` or similar?

```
class LitRf{
  const char* data_;
  size_t size_;
public:
  LitRf(const char* /*?*/ s) : data_{s},size_{sizeof(s)} { /*?*/ }
};
```

Comment: The best I can come up with is to provide a templated overload that static_asserts, or use the explicit keyword.

Comment: @Borgleader But i don't think there is a way to distinguish between a string literal and a const char array.

Comment: @Borgleader How would you `static_assert` that something is a string literal? And how could `explicit` help here? Actually, if you can `static_assert` that something is a string literal, you can also use the same condition with SFINAE to control overload resolution not to bind to the function in the first place.

Comment: @Borgleader Please share it.

Comment: I guess the best you can do is to use `const char (&s)[N]` (with `template<size_t N>`) as the parameter type. But it also binds to any const char array other than a string literal.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [Well it sort of does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8ea43728651593c), like I said "the best i can come up with" or i should have said closest. I dont think what OP wants/needs is doable 100%.

Comment: Demo code for my last comment: http://ideone.com/d9olzv

Comment: @Borgleader None of your test calls is called with a string literal. They both use variables, not literals. I understand the question that exactly that is what should be probihited...

Comment: @leemes your solution also binds to non-const char arrays.

Comment: I know. You cannot change that. Constness can always be added, but not removed. You can only add a non-const overload, but `=delete` it.

Comment: Did you really mean `sizeof(s)`? Because that's 1 in your case... You probably meant `strlen(s)` or `sizeof(s) - 1` if `s` is an array. Or `sizeof(s)` even in that case? Note the terminating zero, which is included in the array size, but not in the string size (strlen).

Comment: @leemes `sizeof` is usually 4 (32 bit archs, CHAR_BIT==8) or 8 (64 bit archs) for a pointer, or the storage size (including the terminating 0) for a literal or array. I meant for my `size_` to store the storage size (exactly like in your answer), but subtracting or not subtracting 1 from the size bears little relevance to the question. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I meant 4 of course ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the best you can do is to use `const char (&s)[N]` (with `template<size_t N>`) as the parameter type. But it also binds to any const char array other than a string literal.

Add a deleted non-const char array constructor to prohibit calling it with a non-const array.

```
class LitRf
{
    const char* data_;
    Sz size_;
public:
    template<size_t N>
    LitRf(char const (&s)[N])
        : data_{s}, size_{N}
    {}

    template<size_t N>
    LitRf(char (&s)[N]) = delete;
};
```

Other than that, you can use a macro wrapper, which (when the constructor is never used without it) makes it only possible to construct an object from a literal, not even via a variable.

```
#define MakeLitRf(s) LitRf(s "")
```

The idea is to concatenate two string literals, of which the second one is just an empty string. This is only possible if the first is also a string literal; putting a variable there is a syntax error. After macro expansion, the compiler sees something like `LitRf("foo" "")` which is equivalent to `LitRf("foo")`. Some examples:

```
auto x = MakeLitRf("foo");  // works

const char *foo = "foo";
auto x = MakeLitRf(foo);    // fails

auto x = LitRf(foo);        // works, but we want it to fail...
```

In the last case, the user unintentionally (or intentionally?) didn't use the macro, making our work worthless. To make it fail too, add a hidden parameter to the constructor, which is required to be added when called directly (and in the macro's definition, of course):

```
class LitRf
{
    const char* data_;
    Sz size_;
public:
    // Called by the macro MakeLitRf. Unlikely to be called directly unless the user knows what he's doing.
    LitRf(const char *s, void *)
        : data_{s}, size_{N}
    {}

    // Called without macro! Throw a compiler error, explaining what's wrong.
    LitRf(const char *s)
    {
        static_assert(false, "Please use the macro `MakeLitRf` with a string literal to construct a `LitRf`.");
    }
};

#define MakeLitRf(s) LitRf(s "", nullptr)
```

Answer (score 3):

C++11 removed the only formal way to detect a string literal as such, namely via its implicit conversion to pointer to non-const.

Anyway using the little trick one had to employ a macro.

In C++11 and later the best you can do is to establish a strong convention that *an array of `const` character type* is a literal.

I.e., with your example,

```
class LitRf
{
private:
    const char* data_;
    Sz size_;

    template< size_t n >
    LitRf( char (&)[n] ) = delete;

public:
    template< size_t n >
    LitRf( char const (&s)[n] )
        : data_{s}, size_{sizeof(s) - 1}
    {}
};
```

Note the use of `size_t` instead of a possibly signed type `Sz`. This ensure that the code will compile with g++. Unfortunately that compiler, or older versions of it, has a bug where it's quite insistent on `size_t`, or else it refuses to accept the code.

Comment: Thanks. `char const []` ~ `string literal` is a reasonable compromise. Unfortunately, this will also initialize from a non-const char array. (Never mind the `Sz`. I didn't know it was anything -- I use it as a `typedef` for `std::size_t` in my namespace)

Comment: But you can't differentiate between an array of `const char` and a `const` array of `char`

Comment: Why `sizeof(s) - 1`? I know, the terminating 0, but OP didn't subtract that originally.

Comment: Ah, forget it - I guess OP didn't mean to do `sizeof(s)` because that's 1 in his case - he probably meant `strlen` which in turn would indeed match your code.

Comment: Added an inaccessible and deleted constructor to prevent construction from array of non-`const` `char`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class LitRf{
  const char* data_;
  Sz size_;
public:
  LitRf(const char* /*?*/ s) : data_{s},size_{sizeof(s)} { /*?*/ }
  LitRf(char*) = delete;
};
```